# How to insert ContentContol in footnote with specific range word.interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

How to go add content control in specific start and end range of footnote? I can add content control in document.range, but I am unable to add in footnote, please help to do this. If anyone reply quickly, I will be proved of you.

```
public void FindItalicFootnote(String FindText)
{
    foreach (Word.Footnote footNote in Word.Document.Footnotes)
    {
        Word.Range RngFind = footNote.Range;
        RngFind.Find.Forward = true;

        if (RngFind.Find.Execute(FindText))
        {
            while (RngFind.Find.Found)
            {
                RngFind.Select();
                object strtRange = Word.Selection.Range.Start;
                object endRange = Word.Selection.Range.End;
                string placeHolder = "";
                bool findCase = false;

                if (Word.Selection.Range.ParentContentControl == null && Word.Selection.Range.ContentControls.Count == 0)
                {
                    RngFind.Select();

                    while (Word.Selection.Previous(Unit: Word.WdUnits.wdWord, Count: 1).Font.Italic == -1)
                    {
                        Word.Selection.Previous(Unit: Word.WdUnits.wdWord, Count: 1).Select();
                        strtRange = Word.Selection.Range.Start;
                        placeHolder = "{VerifiedBy='Italic'}";
                        findCase = true;
                    }

                    Word.ContentControl CC = RngFind.ContentControls.Add(Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText,
                    footNote.range(strtRange, endRange));
//my query is, how to say footNote.range(start, end), in main part I wrote as Word.Document.range(startRange, endRange)
                    CC.Title = "Case Reference";
                    CC.Tag = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    CC.SetPlaceholderText(Text: placeHolder);
                }

                RngFind.Find.Execute(FindText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards,
Saran

Comment: What is VWord here?
     strtRange = VWord.selection.Range.Start;

Comment: Thanks Gopal for quick review, it was typo error, i modified now.

Comment: Hi Gopal, pls give me, any suggestion of this query!

Comment: Hi Saravanan, I don't have much experience Word add-ins so I don't know how much help I can be of. Just for a little effort, have you tried "Word.Selection.Range.Start" in place of strtRange and similarly for endRange ?

Comment: Thanks Gobal, I completed by another way.

Comment: Glad to know that Saravanan! Please do post your approach as an answer to your question so that it may be useful in future.